# What vimrc should I use in Linux?

Tags: linux, vim

I have installed vim by

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Now I want to customize it, but there are two `vimrc` files – one in `/etc`, second is in `/usr/share` folder. Both have a `vimrc` file.

Why are there two vim folders and which one should I use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither. You want to create a *new* file, `.vimrc` – notice the dot at the beginning – and place it in your `$HOME` (`/home/your-username/`) folder. (It'll be hidden from `ls` without `-a` option because of the dot.)

Comment: thanks, but why then there are vim folders in /etc and /usr/share?

Comment: The one in `/usr/share` is the default settings that come with the program applied to all users, and will be overwritten if you upgrade your vim package -- so you don't want to make changes there. The one in `/etc` is for making changes which affect all users that won't be overwritten when the package is updated. But a `.vimrc` is a very personal thing, and generally, you only want to make changes that affect you, so they go in your home folder.